# boost::asio completion handler on async_connect never called again after first failure

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing a small client class that uses boost asio to connect to a remote socket. It should be able to try to reconnect if the initial connection failed.

When testing for that scenario, i.e. there is no open remote socket, the completion handler of async_connect got called correctly the first time. But my completion handler will never be called again for the second attempt when m_state goes into State_Connect again. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test() : m_socket(m_io)
        {
        }

        void update()
        {
            switch (m_state)
            {
                case State_Connect:
                    std::cout << "Start connect\n";
                    m_socket.async_connect(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 33000),
                        boost::bind(&Test::onCompleted, this, asio::placeholders::error));
                    m_state = State_Connecting;
                    break;

                case State_Connecting:
                    if (m_error)
                    {
                        m_error.clear();
                        std::cout << "Could not connect\n";
                        m_state = State_Connect;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            m_io.poll_one();
        }

    private:
        void onCompleted(const bs::error_code& error)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                m_error = error;
                m_socket.close();
            }
        }

        enum State
        {
            State_Connect,
            State_Connecting,
        };
        State           m_state = State_Connect;

        asio::io_service    m_io;
        tcp::socket         m_socket;
        bs::error_code      m_error;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test test;
    for (;;)
    {
        test.update();
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:
    Start connect
    Could not connect
    Start connect

But I expect it to repeat indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/stopped.html)

> When an io_context object is stopped, calls to run(), run_one(),
>   poll() or poll_one() will return immediately without invoking any
>   handlers.

When you call `poll_one()` and no handler is ready, `poll_one()` function marks `io_service` as stopped. `poll_one()` has nothing to do when `m_state` is `State_Connecting` and in this moment io_service is marked as stopped due to the empty queue of handlers.

You can test if `io_service` is stopped, if so call `reset`:

```
if (m_io.stopped())
   m_io.reset();
m_io.poll_one();
```